# How to configure the FujiFilm X-T30 to take a selfie while holding a baby?

Tags: focus, fujifilm

I'm trying to take a selfie while holding a baby, but the FujiFilm X-T30 keeps only me in focus, leaving the baby is out of focus. Is it possible with one of the auto settings to keep both of us in focus in the selfie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the baby is out of focus because it is moving around too much, you can compensate by increasing the shutter speed.  Using a tripod and the self timer may also be helpful.

If the baby is out of focus because it is not within the [depth of field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field), you can increase DOF by:

- Increasing the distance between subject and camera.
- Decreasing the focal length of the lens.
- Stopping down the aperture (by using a larger F-number).

For a selfie, the only factor you have much control over is the aperture.  Start with the largest aperture (smallest F-number), and take test shots after stopping down (increasing F-numbers).  Usually, the value changes in 1/3-stop increments, so to limit the number of test shots, increase the F-number three times between each shot.  The standard sequence is: 1.4, 2, 2.8, 4, 5.6, 8, 11, 16, 22.

Note: If you set everything to Auto, except for one setting, the camera will automatically adjust them for you.  So while it isn't fully auto, it may be close enough.

Comment: FWIW: Fuji publishes a cellphone app that will let you see the camera's viewfinder picture and press the shutter button remotely. It's got some boring name like "Camera Remote," but you can find it easily enough if you search the app store for "fujufilm." Be warned though, it's a Royal Pain to get it to connect to the camera... Can take a minute or more sometimes. (Don't ask me how I know.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I also tried that app... once.  "Royal Pain" is an understatement.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off face detection in the auto-focus, it likely has problems recognizing the baby as a face (eyes closed? features too soft?).

Dress the baby with something with high contrast (checkered  bonnet) and use "classic" autofocus, cameras focus on the closest object in that mode.

Comment: "cameras focus on the closest object in that mode" – Then the problem will be that the baby is in focus, but OP is not.